# Solving nonlinear systems of equations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I'm receiving an error with this simple code, the problem is that the error only appears with one of the equations that I need (`78 * x**0.3 * y**0.8 - 376`).

The error : `invalid value encountered in double_scalars ; F[0] = 78 * x**0.3 * y**0.8 - 376`

If I erase  `* y**0.8` from the first equation, the code runs perfectly, but obviously it doesn't work for me.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def Funcion(z):
   x = z[0]
   y = z[1]

   F = np.empty((2))
   F[0] = 78 * x**0.3 * y**0.8 - 376
   F[1] = 77 * x**0.5 * y - 770
   return F

zGuess = np.array([1,1])
z = fsolve(Funcion,zGuess)
print(z)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python scipy.optimize: Using fsolve with multiple first guesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057022/python-scipy-optimize-using-fsolve-with-multiple-first-guesses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the nonlinear equation system F(x,y) = 0 subject to x, y >= 0, which is equivalent to minimize the euclidean norm ||F(x,y)|| s.t. x,y >= 0. To solve this constrained optimization problem, you can use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def Funcion(z):
   x = z[0]
   y = z[1]

   F = np.empty((2))
   F[0] = 78 * x**0.3 * y**0.8 - 376
   F[1] = 77 * x**0.5 * y - 770
   return F

# initial point
zGuess = np.array([1.0, 1.0])

# bounds x, y >= 0
bounds = [(0, None), (0, None)]

# Solve the constrained optimization problem
z = minimize(lambda z: np.linalg.norm(Funcion(z)), x0=zGuess, bounds=bounds)

# Print the solution
print(z.x)
```

Answer (score 2):

`F[0]` will be complex if `y` is negative. `fsolve` doesn't support complex root finding.