# Solve equation using fsolve with inequality equations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am having trouble understanding how to add inequality equation to fsolve function.

for example:

This are the packages:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
```

These is the equations I want to use:

```
x1 >= 0.4 and x1 <= 0.7
x2 >= 0.2 and x2 <= 0.4
5x2**2 + 2x1**3 = 2
```

and this is the function I am trying to create:

```
myFunc(z):
    x1 = z[0]
    x2 = z[1]
    
    F = np.empty((3))
    F[0] = x1 >= 0.4 and x1 <= 0.7 # <-- This is the first equation
    F[1] = x2 >= 0.2 and x2 <= 0.4 # <-- this is the second equation
    F[2] = 5x2**2 + 2x1**3 = 2 # <-- this is the third equation
    return F
```

and then we call the fsolve:

```
zGuess = np.array([0.3,0.3])
z = fsolve(myFunction,zGuess)
print(z)
```

Any ideas on how to set inequality equations?

Comment: Are you sure the bounds on the variables are correct? There's no point which satisfies the third equation, see `0.4**3 + 0.2**2 = 0.041 < 0.7`.

Comment: you are right. I fixed it

Comment: If my answer was helpful, it would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The `fsolve` method neither can handle inequality constraints nor bounds on the variables. Your first two constraints are simple box constraints, i.e. bounds on the variables, so you just want to solve the nonlinear equation system `2x1**3 + 5x**2 == 2` subject to variable bounds. This can be formulated as a constrained minimization problem, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897046/solving-nonlinear-systems-of-equations/66899191#66899191):

```
For F(x) = 2x1**3 + 5x**2 - 2 you want to solve

min ||F(x)|| 

s.t. 0.4 <= x1 <= 0.7, 
     0.2 <= x2 <= 0.4
```

This constrained optimization problem can easily be solved with [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) as follows:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def obj(x): return 5*x[1]**2 + 2*x[0]**3 - 2

# Set the variable bounds
bounds = [(0.4, 0.7), (0.2, 0.4)]

# Set initial guess
x0 = np.array([0.3, 0.3])

# Solve the problem (res.x contains your solution)
res = minimize(lambda x: np.linalg.norm(obj(x)), x0=x0, bounds=bounds)
```

Note that there's no point within your bounds that satisfies the nonlinear equation. Anyway, as we minimized the euclidian norm of the residual, we obtained the best possible point.