# Solve a system of nonlinear equations with constraints on the variables

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve nine nonlinear equations with nine variables using fsolve in python. But I don't know how to set the constraints to the variables. Besides, the iteration of fsolve is not making good progress with the current code.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

KH = 3.39E-02
Kw = 1.00E-14
KC1 = 4.47E-07
KC2 = 4.69E-11
KP1 = 6.92E-03
KP2 = 6.17E-08
KP3 = 4.79E-13
K = 1
Pt = 0.1
pCO2 = 0.0004

def equations(p):
    q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9 = p
    e1 = q1/pCO2-KH
    e2 = q2*q3-Kw
    e3 = q2*q4/q1-KC1
    e4 = q2*q5/q4-KC2
    e5 = q2*q7/q6-KP1
    e6 = q2*q8/q7-KP2
    e7 = q2*q9/q8-KP3
    e8 = q3+q4+2*q5+q7+2*q8+3*q9-q2-K
    e9 = q6+q7+q8+q9-Pt
    return [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9]

root = fsolve(equations, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

print(root)
```

All the equations are actually equal to 0, but apparently fsolve could not take 0 as the first guess.
The constraint is that all the variables should be positive. How could I find the solutions?

Thanks for the suggestion of using scipy.optimize.minimize.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

KH = 3.39E-02
Kw =    1.00E-14
KC1 = 4.47E-07
KC2 =   4.69E-11
KP1 = 6.92E-03
KP2 = 6.17E-08
KP3 =   4.79E-13
K = 1
Pt = 0.1
pCO2 = 0.0004

def equations(p):
    q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9 = p
    
    E = np.empty((9))
    E[0] = q1/pCO2-KH
    E[1] = q2*q3-Kw
    E[2] = q2*q4/q1-KC1
    E[3] = q2*q5/q4-KC2
    E[4] = q2*q7/q6-KP1
    E[5] = q2*q8/q7-KP2
    E[6] = q2*q9/q8-KP3
    E[7] = q3+q4+2*q5+q7+2*q8+3*q9-q2-K
    E[8] = q6+q7+q8+q9-Pt
    return E

#initial point
pGuess = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

#bounds q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9 >= 0
bounds = [(0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None)]

# Solve the constrained optimization problem
p = minimize(lambda p: np.linalg.norm(equations(p)), x0=pGuess, bounds=bounds)

print(p.x)
```

But I encountered dividing by 0 during the calculation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve equation using fsolve with inequality equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034006/solve-equation-using-fsolve-with-inequality-equations)