# Method of moments for a mixed gaussian

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to solve for the parameters in a mixed gaussian through the method of moments in python.

I've got my set up from the [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

I've set up the system of equations in a function, but when I use `fsolve` from scipy, I'm having issues with the output, after each run I get an error and the output is different.

```
def myFunction(var):
   (mu_1, sigm_1, mu_2, sigm_2, p) = var
   N = 10_000

   data1 = np.random.normal(1,.5,size = int(N/3))
   data2 = np.random.normal(-1,.5,size = int(N*2/3)+1)
   data = np.concatenate((data1,data2))


   F = np.empty((5))
   F[0] = p*mu_1 + (1-p)*mu_2  +  0
   F[1] = p*(mu_1**2 + sigm_1**2) + (1-p) * (mu_2**2 + sigm_2**2)  + np.std(data)**2
   F[2] = p*(mu_1**3 + 3*mu_1*sigm_1**2) + \
          (1-p) * (mu_2**3 + 3*mu_2 * sigm_2**2) + 0
   F[3] = p*(mu_1**4 + 6*mu_1**2 * sigm_1**2 + 3*sigm_1**2) + \
          (1-p) * (mu_2**4 + 6*mu_2**2 * sigm_2**2 + 3*sigm_2**4) + 3*np.std(data)**4
   F[4] = p*(mu_1**5 + 10*mu_1**3 * sigm_1**2 + 15*mu_1 * sigm_1**4) + \
          (1-p) * (mu_2**5 + 10*mu_2**3 * sigm_2**2 + 15*mu_2*sigm_2**4) + 0

   return F

z_guess = [1,1,1,1,1]
z = sp.optimize.fsolve(myFunction,z_guess)
print(z)
```

and the error I receive is the following

```
RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

I'm not quite sure where my issue is, maybe there's something that I'm missing.

Comment: Please include imports in your minimal example. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057022/python-scipy-optimize-using-fsolve-with-multiple-first-guesses

Comment: As you can see, this isn't an error, but a warning, so you can probably ignore it and see what happens. The initial guess is also important: "bad" guesses can lead to poor convergence and even completely different results. Also note that gaussian mixtures are [notoriously difficult to estimate](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.06930) with the method of moments. It's much simpler to use maximum likelihood estimation via the EM algorithm, although it also has a whole lot of shortcomings.