# Is there a way to solve f(x) = b, constrained on x_i >= 0?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, linear-programming

I want to solve a linear system of equations `Ax = b` subject to `x_i >= 0`.

This is of course a case of linear programming. The problem is that `A` is too large to be created. I can, however, calculate `Ax` efficiently.

So I have access to `f(x) = Ax`, `x`, and `b`.

I prefer using pytorch (to utilize the GPU). What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: multivariate non-linear solver with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995862/python-multivariate-non-linear-solver-with-constraints)

Comment: All serious LP solvers assume A is sparse.

Comment: If it's sparse and only dimensions are big, follow Erwins comment. If not, there is the are of *matrix-free* or (sometimes just) *first-order* (LP) methods. But available software is limited.