# Vectorizing fsolve/ solving multiple nonlinear equations for multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, equation, solver

fsolve finds a solution of (a system of) nonlinear equations from a starting estimate. I can vectorize my function call to use fsolve on multiple starting points and potentially find multiple solutions, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054758/python-finding-multiple-roots-of-nonlinear-equation). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python) question it is described how to solve multiple nonlinear equations with fsolve. However, I am having problems combining the two, i.e. solving multiple nonlinear equations from multiple starting values. I know that I can always loop through my starting values and use the second posts answer, but, having to do this for possibly more than a 100000 points, I'm really trying to find a more pythonic (and hopefully faster) solution.

I tried different ways, for example the following (and many others):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def equations(x): # x+y^2-4, sin(x)+x*y-3
    ret = np.array([x[:,0]+x[:,1]**2-4, np.sin(x[:,0]) + x[:,0]*x[:,1] - 3]).T
    return ret

p1 = np.array([0,0]) # first initial value
p2 = np.array([1,1]) # second initial value
x0 = np.array([p1,p2])

print(x0[0,1])
print(equations(x0))
print(fsolve(equations, x0=x0))
```

The shapes and all work, but `fsolve` throws: 'IndexError: too many indices for array'
I tried some different ways, but I can't work out any functioning code on this besides using a simple for loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about using joblib ? This is not a straight vectorization, but the different starting points will be executed in parallel.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def equations(x): # x+y^2-4, sin(x)+x*y-3
    ret = np.array([x[0]+x[1]**2-4, np.sin(x[0]) + x[0]*x[1] - 3]).T
    return ret

p1 = np.array([0,0]) # first initial value
p2 = np.array([1,1]) # second initial value
x0 = [p1, p2]

sol = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(fsolve)(equations, x0=p) for p in x0)
print(sol)
```

The parameter `n_jobs` controls how many concurrent jobs are running.

Comment: I never heard of joblib before, but I am going to take a look at it thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def eq(x):
     return x[0] + x[1]**2 - 4 , np.sin(x[0]) + x[0]*x[1] - 3

fsolve(eq, [0, 1])

output: array([ 1.23639399,  1.6624097 ])
```

In this case, I would suggest using a brute force method:

```
x0 = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(range(10), range(10))]

for xnot in x0:
    print(fsolve(eq, xnot))

[  1.33088471e-07   2.09094320e+00]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
[ 1.23639399  1.6624097 ]
```

Comment: This finds one solution from starting point (0,1). I want several solutions at once.

Comment: I added that to my answer. Then use np.isclose() to screen out same answer.

Comment: I mentioned that I know I can do this in a for loop, I'm searching for a vectorized version