# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars as I try to find equation values

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to solve a simple equation:

`x^2 - 4 = 0` using `fslolve`.

```
 from scipy.optimize import fsolve,leastsq
 import math
 import numpy as np

 f = lambda x : math.pow(x,2) - 4

 fsolve(f, np.linspace(0,1,10))
```

But I get an error saying `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

I cannot understand the reason for this. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Show the traceback.  We (and you) need to know exactly where this is happening.  I can make a guess (feeding a value to `math.pow`, which only accepts a scalar). but you need to practice good debugging skills.

Comment: Why are you passing the `linspace` to fsolve instead of a single value? I think you have to pass a ndarray with the same shape as x to fsolve, so it expects a number or a size-1 array: `fsolve(f, 1)` works for me

Comment: You are passing an array to `lambda` function which is expecting a single scalar value.

Comment: @pdpino I do not understand the second argument with `fsolve`. Though it works, but what is it denote? What does your passing `1` mean here?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass that `linspace` array (10 values) to `fsolve`?  Are you trying solve a scalar equation, or an array one (10 element `x` input, and 10 element value)?  And why `math.pow` at all?  `x**2` works just as well with Python and `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj I had read the snippet somewhere and was confused on how to use the `fsolve` function. Could you please tell what does `fsolve(f, 1)` this really mean? The solution is the same with `fsolve(f, 2)` and same with `fsolve(f, 3)`.

Comment: Have you read the `fsolve` docs?

Comment: @hpaulj I did https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html but could not understand.

Comment: @hpaulj I want to solve this equation https://pasteboard.co/IfBU2ub.png using fsolve. Would you have some suggestions?

Comment: The second argument to fsolve is a starting point to solve the equation. I don't know the fsolve internals, but it should solve the equation using an iterative algorithm, where you start with a possible solution (if you use `fsolve(f, 1)` it starts with 1), and then tries to change the solution until it gets to the actual result (in this case 2). An example of this kind of algorithm is the Newton's method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). So, for e.g., if x were a 2-dimension vector, you would would pass a vector with two dimensions, e.g. (0, 0).

Comment: @pdpino Would you be able to explain in context with https://pasteboard.co/IfBU2ub.png

Comment: With the given equation, using `fsolve(f, 0)` finds 0.2 (a solution close to 0); `fsolve(f, 2)` finds 2.08 (a solution close to 2). (which are 2 different solutions for the same equation)

Comment: Also, you could leverage the second argument to find multiple roots. You would have to change `math.pow` by `np.power` (so it can receive a ndarray) and pass an array as the second argument to fsolve, like `np.array([0, 2])`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13055684/9951939